# Get number of affected rows/documents in AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

How do I get the number of affected documents in AQL?

Given a query like this:

```
FOR u IN users
  FILTER u.active == true
  UPDATE u WITH { numberOfLogins: 0 } IN users
```

How can I get the number of affected documents?

Answer (score 2):

The query itself will not return any documents, but can provide the number of documents updated. The following example shows how to do it in the ArangoShell:

```
var query = "FOR u IN users FILTER u.active == true UPDATE u WITH { numberOfLogins: 0 } IN users";
var stmt = db._createStatement(query);
var result = stmt.execute();
var stats = result.getExtra().stats;
print(stats);
```

In my case that returned something like the following:

```
{ 
  "writesExecuted" : 50, 
  "writesIgnored" : 0, 
  "scannedFull" : 100, 
  "scannedIndex" : 0  
}
```

`writesExecuted` is probably the figure you are after. It indicates how many document updates were done. How to get to the figure from language-specific drivers might be different (likely depends on the language and driver), but ArangoDB's HTTP API that all drivers use provides this figure.

Comment: But there is no way to do this directly in AQL? So there is no possible pendant to mysql's ROW_COUNT()?

Comment: Not directly in AQL. An AQL query is a single statement anyway, and an `UPDATE` will always be at the end of the query, so the number of rows updated cannot be passed to some other operation in the same query.

Comment: Since 2.4, the modified documents can optionally be returned from an AQL `UPDATE` query. Not sure if that helps, but it is an option.